Doing Ascii and number inserts in a table
I have a table called Locations which is used to store the aisles and rows of a supermarket.



SupermarketId
Aisles
Rows




Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell 3


Cell 5
Cell 5
Cell 6



Initially I have no entries in the Locations table for a given supermarket.  Using a stored procedure which I have created I will do inserts in the Locations table representing the number of aisles and rows of that supermartket.
The Aisles are represented by the alphabets (A,B,C...) while the rows are represented by the numbers (1, 2, 3...)
For example, for supermarket 1, which initially has 2 aisles and 3 rows, the inserts done will be:



SupermarketId
Aisles
Rows




1
A
1


1
A
2


1
A
3


1
B
1


1
B
2


1
B
3



Now I want to add additional aisles or rows to the supermarket.  I have 2 stored procedures to do this.
If for example, I want to increase the number of aisles to 4 and number of rows to 5, the inserts are done correctly.
I have my aisles A - D each having rows 1 - 5
But if I want to add an additional aisle and row, that is set to 5 aisles and 6 rows in total, the inserts which I get are.
Aisles A - F, each having 6 rows.



SupermarketId
Aisles
Rows




1
A
1


1
A
2


1
A
3


1
B
1


1
B
2


1
B
3


1
A
4


1
A
5


1
A
6


1
B
4


1
B
5


1
B
6


1
C
1


1
C
2


1
C
3


1
C
4


1
C
5


1
C
6


1
D
1


1
D
2


1
D
3


1
D
4


1
D
5


1
D
6


1
E
1


1
E
2


1
E
3


1
E
4


1
E
5


1
E
6



I am somehow getting an additional aisles.
Below are my stored procedures:
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UPDATE_LOCATIONS]
    @supermarketId BIGINT, -- Warehouse Id
    @noAisles BIGINT, -- New number of aisles
    @noRows BIGINT -- New number of rows
    
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @oldNoAisles BIGINT;
    DECLARE @oldNoRows BIGINT;

    SELECT 

        @oldNoAisles = WAR.Aisles,
        @oldNoRows = WAR.Rows

    FROM SUPERMARKTETS WAR
    WHERE WAR.SupermarketId = @supermarketId

    IF (@oldNoRows > @noRows)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM AR_WAREHOUSE_LOCATIONS
        WHERE SupermarketId = @supermarketId
        AND WAL_N_ROW = @oldNoRows;
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            --EXECUTE [dbo].[AR_SP_ADD_WAREHOUSE_LOCATIONS] @supermarketId, @noAisles, @noRows
            EXECUTE [dbo].[SP_ADD_LOCATIONS] @supermarketId, @oldNoAisles, @noRows

        END

    IF (@oldNoAisles > @noAisles)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @aisleToDelete VARCHAR(50) = CHAR(@oldNoAisles + 64);
    
        DELETE FROM AR_WAREHOUSE_LOCATIONS
        WHERE SupermarketId = @supermarketId
        AND WAL_CH_AISLE = @aisleToDelete;
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE [dbo].[SP_ADD_LOCATIONS] @supermarketId, @noAisles, @noRows
        END

    UPDATE SUPERMARKTETS
    SET Aisles = @noAisles,
        Rows = @noRows
    WHERE SupermarketId = @supermarketId;

END;

And
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ADD_LOCATIONS]
    @supermarketId bigint,
    @NewAisleCount bigint,
    @NewRowCount bigint
AS
BEGIN
    -- Determine the starting aisle for new aisles (e.g., 'D' for the 4th aisle)
    DECLARE @StartingAisle nvarchar(50);
    SET @StartingAisle = CHAR(ASCII('A') + (SELECT MAX(ASCII(Aisles)) - ASCII('A') + 1 FROM Locations WHERE SupermarketId = @supermarketId));

    -- Insert new aisles and rows for the new aisles
    DECLARE @NewAisle nvarchar(50);
    SET @NewAisle = @StartingAisle;
    DECLARE @RowNumber bigint;
    SET @RowNumber = 1;

    WHILE @RowNumber <= @NewRowCount
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Locations (SupermarketId, Aisles, Rows)
        VALUES (@supermarketId, @NewAisle, @RowNumber);

        SET @RowNumber = @RowNumber + 1;
    END;

    -- Insert rows for existing aisles
    DECLARE @ExistingAisle nvarchar(50);
    SET @ExistingAisle = 'A';

    WHILE ASCII(@ExistingAisle) <= ASCII(@StartingAisle)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @RowCount bigint;
        SET @RowCount = (SELECT MAX(Rows) FROM Locations WHERE SupermarketId = @supermarketId AND Aisles = @ExistingAisle);

        WHILE @RowCount < @NewRowCount
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Locations (SupermarketId, Aisles, Rows)
            VALUES (@supermarketId, @ExistingAisle, @RowCount + 1);

            SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1;
        END;

        SET @ExistingAisle = CHAR(ASCII(@ExistingAisle) + 1);
    END;
END;

Can you help me please?

Do you need to use a stored procedure for this? Stored procs are generally a poor choice for business logic. I recommend using app code in python, java, etc - (pick whatever you're most familiar with)

@Bohemian  Yes, else I would have done it in the app code.

FYI the prefix sp_ is reserved, by Microsoft, for Special / System Procedures. It should not be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?

The procedures feel like they have massively overly complicated the issue. You could just use a tally to add more rows and aisles to your table, and then a single INSERT on the values that don't exists in the table. Perhaps something like this:
CREATE TABLE dbo.SuperMarketAisles (SuperMarketID int,
                                    Aisle char(1),
                                    Row tinyint)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UI_SuperMarketRowAisle ON dbo.SuperMarketAisles (SuperMarketID, Aisle, Row);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SuperMarketAisles (SuperMarketID,Aisle, Row)
SELECT 1,
       Aisle,
       Row
FROM (VALUES('A'),('B'),('C'))A(Aisle)
     CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3))R(Row);
GO
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [fn].[Tally] (@LastNumber bigint, @Zero bit) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN

    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        WHERE @Zero = 0
          AND @LastNumber IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (ISNULL(@LastNumber,0))
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7) --Up to 10,000,000 rows
    SELECT I
    FROM Tally T;
GO
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.AddAislesRows @SupermarketID int, @Aisles tinyint, @Rows tinyint AS --Why a BIGINT? What happens when you get to aisle 27, let alone aisle 2,147,483,648?
BEGIN

    WITH RowAisles AS(
        SELECT @SupermarketID AS SuperMarketID,
               CHAR(ASCII('A')+A.I) AS Aisle,
               R.I AS Row
        FROM (SELECT MAX(Aisle) AS MaxAisle,
                     MAX(Row) AS MaxRow
              FROM dbo.SuperMarketAisles SMA WITH (UPDLOCK)
              WHERE SMA.SupermarketID = @SupermarketID) M --Assumes rows already exists for the supermarket
             CROSS APPLY fn.Tally(@Aisles + ASCII(M.MaxAisle) - ASCII('A'),0) AS A
             CROSS APPLY fn.Tally(@Rows + M.MaxRow,1) R)
    INSERT INTO dbo.SuperMarketAisles (SuperMarketID, Aisle, Row)
    SELECT SuperMarketID,
           Aisle,
           Row
    FROM RowAisles RA
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM dbo.SuperMarketAisles SMA
                      WHERE SMA.SuperMarketID = RA.SuperMarketID
                        AND SMA.[Row] = RA.[Row]
                        AND SMA.Aisle = RA.Aisle);
END;
GO
SELECT *
FROM  dbo.SuperMarketAisles;
GO
EXEC dbo.AddAislesRows 1,2,2;
GO
SELECT *
FROM  dbo.SuperMarketAisles;

If you change the procedure to take the last aisle and row (rather than the number to add), then it's actually slightly simpler:
INSERT INTO dbo.SuperMarketAisles (SuperMarketID,Aisle, Row)
SELECT 2,
       Aisle,
       Row
FROM (VALUES('A'),('B'))A(Aisle)
     CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3))R(Row);
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.LastAislesRows @SupermarketID int, @LastAisle char(1), @LastRow tinyint AS --Why a BIGINT? What happens when you get to aisle 27, let alone aisle 2,147,483,648?
BEGIN

    WITH RowAisles AS(
        SELECT @SupermarketID AS SuperMarketID,
               CHAR(ASCII('A')+A.I) AS Aisle,
               R.I AS Row
        FROM fn.Tally(ASCII(@LastAisle) - ASCII('A'),0) AS A
             CROSS APPLY fn.Tally(@LastRow,1) R)
    INSERT INTO dbo.SuperMarketAisles (SuperMarketID, Aisle, Row)
    SELECT SuperMarketID,
           Aisle,
           Row
    FROM RowAisles RA
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM dbo.SuperMarketAisles SMA
                      WHERE SMA.SuperMarketID = RA.SuperMarketID
                        AND SMA.[Row] = RA.[Row]
                        AND SMA.Aisle = RA.Aisle);
END;
GO
EXEC dbo.LastAislesRows 2,'F',5;
GO
SELECT *
FROM  dbo.SuperMarketAisles;
GO

db<>fiddle

GENERATE_SERIES does not exist for my SQL Server version.

You could use a UDF instead then, instead of GENERATE_SERIES. There are plenty of examples. With no version specific tag, I assumed you were using the latest version of SQL Server, @Alis .

I tried the functions provided and it does not work.  If initially I had 2 aisles and 3 rows, now I add 4 more aisles and 5 more rows, I am getting aisles A - F but the I have only 3 rows for A and 5 rows for F.  It should be 5 rows for each aisles.

So you are also adding rows to the existing aisles? We don't have any sample data or expected results here. Perhaps giving that, idealling as DML and DDL, would help here.

I edited my question so you have an idea of how it should be.

Perhaps that, @Alis ? (Used my own DDL and DML as wasn't provided.)
